# What is using all the space in my external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I found an old hard drive that I used to back up files from my old Macbook. I plugged it into my Ubuntu machine to see what was on it.

When I look in System Monitor, it shows:

```
Used 443 GB
Free 99 GB
```

It seems to only contain one directory and one file:

```
Backups.backupdb (dir)
tmbootpicker.efi (file)
```

But the when I look at the size of `Backups.backupdb`, it is 854 MB and the size of `tmbootpicker.efi` is 298 KB.

I'm just confused as to what is filling up the external drive.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to view hidden files?

Comment: Ah yes, now I see more files. They still don't even seem to add up to anywhere near the 500 GB.

Comment: @user1551817 How did you check the size? Windows Explorer isn't the best in calculating sizes of directories. Try using some software like TreeSize

Comment: The size of the drive? Using System Monitor. The size of the directory? Just by right clicking and Properties.

Comment: @Ahatius He is using Ubuntu.